# Access Android camera object on runtime (Unity, Vuforia)

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, camera, java-native-interface, vuforia

I'm writing Unity for Android app which uses Vuforia Augmented Reality framework.

I need manually change camera exposure to reach better augmentation. The problem is that Vuforia hides all work with camera and make it inaccessible from outside.

Also Vuforia itself uses JNI to work with device's camera.

When I try to do next in my Android plugin:

```
Camera camera = Camera.open();
```

I got CAMERA_ERROR_EVICTED exception: "Camera was disconnected due to use by higher priority user."

Is it any way to get current Camera object using JNI or any other approach?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: You really can't since Vuforia is using the camera. This requires reverse engineering on the Vuforia SDK if there is a part of it that uses Java to get images from the camera. You can then use `AndroidJavaClass` to steal the instance of the camera that is already opened. Again, you need to be able to see the variables defined in their Java plugin in order to do this.

Comment: Thank you for answer. "You can then use `AndroidJavaClass` to still the instance of the camera that is already opened. " That's exactly what I need. Do you know how to do that?

Comment: Yes but like I said you first have to be to see the variables in the classes which requires disassembly. Find the name of the class then pass it to `AndroidJavaClass` constructor.  Look for for the instance of that class with the `GetStatic` function. With that, you can get the instance of the camera with `Get` or `GetStatic` depending on if it is `static` or not as store it as `AndroidJavaObject`. Finally, you can now access the camera variables or call it's function from Unity.

Comment: See [this](https://forum.unity3d.com/threads/webcamtexture-on-android-focus-mode-fix.327956/) for full example for the Unity `WebCamTexture` stuff **not** Vuforia but that should tell you what the code should look like. Remember, you can't do this without dissembling the Java part of the Vuforia plugin. I think they use both C++ and Java. You only need to see the variables on the Java side.